# Laravel directory to welcome page on a VPS

Tags: laravel, url, vps

Before I was in a shared hosting and had no problem installing and accessing (click next next), Laravel welcome page but I have moved to a bare metal VPS and I am having difficulties to get to the Laravel 5 welcome page. My host tells me to upload the framework to the htdocs directory, but that is exactly what I did and where the app et al are found.

This is the URL scenario.

My web VPS by default shows me its own index.html like this

```
/var/www/virtual/myweb.com/htdocs/index.html
```

and yes, I can correctly access that index through myweb.com

but, of course, all my views are in their Views folder, like this:

```
/var/www/virtual/myweb.com/htdocs/resources/views/welcome.blade.php
```

my routes page (as it is a freshly installed) naturally

```
Route::get('/', function() {

return view('welcome');

});
```

and the URL in my config/app.php file

```
'url' = >env('APP_URL', http://myweb.com');
```

If I do something like this in the URL browser box of course, I get to the file of Laravel 5 welcome  page

```
http://www.myweb.com/resources/views/welcome.blade.php
```

but obviously I don't want to show such path

so, I would like to be able to write myweb.com and directly show my welcome.blade.php

Any ideas as to how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should point you web server (Apache) to a `public` directory of Laravel's project. For example:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/virtual/myweb.com/public/"
<Directory "/var/www/virtual/myweb.com/public/">
```

After rebooting web server normal URLs should work (if you'll set up correct settings).

Comment: spasibo Alexey, prostite, where do I do that ? you mean I should create yet another folder named public and move everything there ?

oh, I think I know what you mean. When I was in shared hosting I also set the document root to /public by going to the domain tools in the cpanel

thank you Великий праздник — День Победы —

Comment: If there is a Control Panel, you could use it. Or just find and edit Apache's config file (usually it's `httpd.conf`): http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost